# Switch between multiple SVN branches in Visual Studio project

Tags: visual-studio, svn

I'm working on a new project that is stored in SVN, and I'm trying to develop a workflow that allows me to keep using Visual Studio as my IDE, but allows me to easily switch my working copy between a number of different branches. I'm currently using TortoiseSVN, and I'm not using an SVN plugin for VS.

The project has multiple long-lived parallel branches (mostly for region-specific feature builds, which need to be kept separate for QA reasons), and I need to be able to transition between them every few days. While I could keep separate working copies for each (and make a new VS project for each one), I would like to try to find a way to easily maintain only 1 working copy, and 1 project.

While the build process is the same for each branch (from visual studio's perspective, at least), some branches have additional source files. So, (I think) I need to be able to rescan the source directory for C and C++ source files to add to the project every time, but I have no idea how to accomplish this.

Is there any way to easily manage a setup like this, or would it be easier to give in and create new projects for each branch? That would make the ability for me to utilize feature branches similarly annoying, but it wouldn't be the end of the world.

Comment: "project"? Your project files should be in source control (since they contain the files included with the project), and switching branches should make it "correct" for that branch. You *may* need to rebuild all when switching, but other than that nothing else should need to be done.

Comment: The Visual Studio project isn't in source control because our setup gives devs free reign over which IDE we use. Again, we aren't building in Visual Studio, just using it to call our external tool via the command line.